# CLPlacemark 'name' returns street address while 'thoroughfare' is returning only the street name

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pulling down the address dictionary from a CLPlacemark and I'm not getting any errors or anything but the keys don't seem to line up with what the Apple documentation shows.

From the CLPlacemark class:

```
// address dictionary properties
var name: String! { get } // eg. Apple Inc.
var thoroughfare: String! { get } // street address, eg. 1 Infinite Loop
var subThoroughfare: String! { get } // eg. 1
...
```

But when I get placemark.name it returns the street address eg. 1 Infinite Loop. And when I get placemark.thoroughfare it only returns the street name, not the number as it looks like it's supposed to. placemark.subThoroughfare does contain the building number though so currently I'm just concatenating subThoroughfare and thoroughfare but I'm concerned that I'll sporadically get two building numbers occasionally if placemark.thoroughfare returns the number and street name.

Is this a bug or what and can I count on concatenating the strings like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like an error in those comments. Reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/thoroughfare) suggests that `thoroughfare` will only return the street name, as you say:

> The street address contains the street name. For example, if the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters, the value for this property would be the string “Infinite Loop”.

Reading the same docs, under [`subThoroughfare`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/subThoroughfare), it looks like you're right there too:

> Subthroughfares provide information such as the street number for the location. For example, if the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters (1 Infinite Loop), the value for this property would be the string “1”.

As for `name`, that's simply the name that the system has for the placemark. For some places, it will just be the address. For others that the system has more information on, I believe it will be something more user-friendly ("Walmart", "Stack Exchange Offices", etc.)

---

Your intentions, though, seem to be simply to get the address of the placemark. For that, I would use the [`addressDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/addressDictionary) property and let the system (namely [`ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/addressbookui/reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary)) handle the nasty parts:

```
address = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(myPlacemark.addressDictionary, false);
```

Note that I believe this will give you the system's best interpretation, and it likely will include the city, state, zip, etc.

Comment: Ahhh! Okay, yes. I didn't read the docs closely enough to notice that they don't line up with the code comments. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Christian You might consider filing a Radar about it, it'd be easy for them to change the comments and prevent more confusion like yours.